# Show that a function $u$ has weak derivatives which satisfy the transport equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives

Let $v \in L^1_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ weakly differentiable, $b\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} $ constant and $u:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $u(x,t):= v(x-bt)$.

Show that $u$ has weak derivatives $ \partial_x u$ and $ \partial_t u$ which satisfy the transport equation $\partial_t u + b \partial_x u = 0$ almost everywhere.

I know the definition of the weak derivative, but since I don´t have any explicit function given I don´t know how to test it. I also wonder if there is a chain rule for weak derivatives, since $u$ is a concatenation of $v$ with $x-bt$.

Could anyone help me out with this problem? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I will have to think through this some more to fully understand it (I was just introduced to this topic) but it looks very promising. I will come back later and accept this as an answer once I thought about it enough. Thank you very much for your help!